# Remove commits from origin

Tags: git, gitlab

I accidentally committed to my origin some commits when intending to clone a project and set a new origin. I have reverted my changes in the repo I want to preserve, but cannot push them to origin.

```
$ git log --pretty=oneline --format=%h

dff98f5
2e97c31
31b8b73
460fae6
c589d7a
edbda48

$git reset --hard 460fae6

On branch master...
```

And here's what doesn't work

```
git push --force origin master

! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@gitlab.com:username/projectname.git'
```

How can I update my Gitlab repo? (I did not see any UI option when on the site.)

Comment: Is it your gitlab repo? I mean, do you have full rights on it? If so you *should* be able to configure hooks on branches.

Comment: @RomainValeri Yes, my repo. I am the owner.

Answer (score 4):

There is an old story of a magician who called up a daemon to protect his stash of stuff (wands, potions, whatever it was).  He told the daemon that he was going away for a few days, and that the daemon should eat anyone who came back into his house.

Three days later, the magician returned to his house, and the daemon ate him.

You have programmed a slightly friendlier daemon—a *pre-receive hook*—into your Gitlab repository.  You told it to bar anyone who tries to *remove* a commit from your repository.  You tried to remove a commit from your repository, using `git push --force`.  Your daemon stopped you from doing that.

If you wish to do that now, you should either remove your daemon, or make it smarter.  Don't eat just *anyone*, eat anyone who is *not you*.

Answer (score 2):

You say you reverted the changes but the command you used was `reset`; you removed the commits from the branch rather than reverting them. Another option would be to actually revert them, creating new commits that undo the unwanted ones. You can do that with the `revert` command:

```sh
git revert 460fae6..dff98f5
```

That way there's no need to force push, you're just adding some more commits. If anyone else is working on the repo with you then this is probably the way to go.

Comment: Practical answer right here. Although, let's note that the problem of not knowing how to configure your repo settings properly *will* cause trouble at some point.